# "Idea" of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Given an elliptic curve $E$, for any given $p$, there are going to have some number of solutions mod $p$, call this $N_p$ between $0$ and $p^2$. In general it will be around $p$ because of [Hasse's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves).

I understand that, roughly, the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture was based on the idea that the higher the rank of $E$, the larger $N_p/p$ will be. I just don't understand why.

Is it just because more of the arbitrary points of $E$ will be rational, and then end up being integers mod p? If this is the case, it seems like having a few copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ shouldn't change the "probability", is it that the effect is subtle and only seen in the limit?

Comment: I think [BSD](https://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/bsd/bsd/node4.html) is [proven](http://math.columbia.edu/~yihang/GZSeminarnotes/talk%201.pdf) when the order of vanishing of $L(1+s,E)$ is $0$ or $1$, so that should count as the idea underlying the BSD conjecture, assuming we can follow the proof.

Comment: @reuns: Motivating BSD by partial progress 20+ years after the original formulation of the conjecture seems somewhat backwards to me.

Comment: @lukemassa: Have you looked at Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer's [original paper](https://eudml.org/doc/150676)? The introduction mentions experimental data that suggested $\prod_{p \leq X} N_p(E)/p \sim C (log X)^g$ where $g$ is the rank of $E$, which motivated the conjecture.